# Nested Case error Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not as versed in SQL as I'd like to be. I'm trying to use the following case to include "Vendor Name" and "Vendor Number" into a report.

Vendor Number

```
CASE WHEN [GLPOST].[SRCELEDGER] = 'AP' 
THEN 
(SELECT LEFT([GLJED].[TRANSREF],
        CHARINDEX('-',[GLJED].[TRANSREF])-1) 
 FROM [GLJED] WHERE [GLJED].[TRANSNBR] = '0000000020' 
     AND [GLPOST].[BATCHNBR] = [GLJED].[BATCHNBR] 
     AND [GLPOST].[ENTRYNBR] = [GLJED].[JOURNALID]
) 
ELSE '' END
```

Vendor Name

```
CASE WHEN [GLPOST].[SRCELEDGER] = 'AP' 
THEN 
(SELECT [APVEN].[VENDNAME] 
 FROM [APVEN] 
 WHERE [APVEN].[VENDORID] = (SELECT LEFT([GLJED].[TRANSREF],
                                    CHARINDEX('-',[GLJED].[TRANSREF])-1) 
                             FROM [GLJED] 
                             WHERE [GLJED].[TRANSNBR] = '0000000020' 
                             AND [GLPOST].[BATCHNBR] = [GLJED].[BATCHNBR] 
                             AND [GLPOST].[ENTRYNBR] = [GLJED].[JOURNALID])
) 
ELSE '' END
```

The problem is, I'm getting error

> "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."

I'm sure it's because a transaction is missing a "-" in the [GLJED].[TRANSREF].

I've tried searching for different ways around this, but I'm doing something wrong. If I remove the "-1", the query runs but does not give me the data I'm looking for. I need the data from the left of the "-" to find the vendor name and number.

I've tried putting another case inside the select statement if the CHARINDEX('-',[GLJED].[TRANSREF]) = 0 but I must be putting it in the wrong spot.

Be gentle, I've been searching!

Comment: it is probably because CHARINDEX('-',[GLJED].[TRANSREF])-1 is -1 when [GLJED].[TRANSREF] doesn't have a - in it.

Comment: Right, I've figured out it's because it's missing "-" and is basically saying "0 - 1" which is causing the error. I just haven't found a way to fix that yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CHARINDEX('-',[GLJED].[TRANSREF])-1` is `-1` when `[GLJED].[TRANSREF]` doesn't have a - (hyphen) in it.

So you can fix a few ways, one is by adding a case in your nested select:

```
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',[GLJED].[TRANSREF]) = 0 THEN [GLJED].[TRANSREF]
ELSE LEFT([GLJED].[TRANSREF],CHARINDEX('-',[GLJED].[TRANSREF])-1) END
```

Becuase you have a nested select in a case statement I would assume your query could probably use some work but just taking being able to modify what I can see it would be:

```
CASE WHEN [GLPOST].[SRCELEDGER] = 'AP' 
THEN 
(SELECT
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',[GLJED].[TRANSREF]) = 0 THEN [GLJED].[TRANSREF]
       ELSE LEFT([GLJED].[TRANSREF],CHARINDEX('-',[GLJED].[TRANSREF])-1) END 

       FROM [GLJED] WHERE [GLJED].[TRANSNBR] = '0000000020' AND [GLPOST].[BATCHNBR] = [GLJED].[BATCHNBR] AND [GLPOST].[ENTRYNBR] = [GLJED].[JOURNALID]) 
ELSE '' END
```

Comment: This worked great, thank you so much you guys are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Like you stated, missing "-" will make invalid length because CHARINDEX return 0 in that case. Adding, minus one makes the length invalid of LEFT function.

Using [substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) and and IndexOf, you won't have this problem.
However, it will return "empty" string when "-" is missing.

```
CASE WHEN [GLPOST].[SRCELEDGER] = 'AP' 
THEN 
(SELECT SELECT SUBSTRING([GLJED].[TRANSREF], 0, CHARINDEX('-', [GLJED].[TRANSREF])) FROM [GLJED] WHERE [GLJED].[TRANSNBR] = '0000000020' AND [GLPOST].[BATCHNBR] = [GLJED].[BATCHNBR] AND [GLPOST].[ENTRYNBR] = [GLJED].[JOURNALID]) 
ELSE '' END

--Return "Value1" for "Value1-Value2-Value3"
--Return "" for "LonelyValue"
```

## EDIT

If you want to return the whole value when "-" is missing, you can use a "CASE WHEN" to handle that case.

```
CASE WHEN [GLPOST].[SRCELEDGER] = 'AP' 
THEN 
(SELECT (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-', [GLJED].[TRANSREF]) <= 0 THEN
            [GLJED].[TRANSREF]
        ELSE
            SUBSTRING([GLJED].[TRANSREF], 0, CHARINDEX('-', [GLJED].[TRANSREF]))
        END)
 FROM [GLJED] WHERE [GLJED].[TRANSNBR] = '0000000020' AND [GLPOST].[BATCHNBR] = [GLJED].[BATCHNBR] AND [GLPOST].[ENTRYNBR] = [GLJED].[JOURNALID]) 
ELSE '' END

--Return "Value1" for "Value1-Value2-Value3"
--Return "LonelyValue" for "LonelyValue"
```

Or to avoid having a "case when" to handle this specific case, you could use the following trick.

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING([GLJED].[TRANSREF], -CHARINDEX('-', [GLJED].[TRANSREF]) + 2, LEN([GLJED].[TRANSREF]))

--Return "Value1" for "Value1-Value2-Value3"
--Return "LonelyValue" for "LonelyValue"
```

However, this trick will misbehave if your value start or end with space(s) because [Len](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) doesn't count them.